# Remote desktop connection to Raspberry Pi without specifying a port

Tags: raspberry-pi, remote-access, vnc, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi running [Debian 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_timeline) (Wheezy) connected on "Site A", where the network is managed by a third-party company and where all ports are closed to the Internet (for security reasons). So, there is no way for me to do any port forwarding to VNC, nor SSH or anything else. That means I just can't access it in any way other than locally, on-site.

However, I need to connect to that device on the X Desktop session (graphical interface) to do some maintenance, and I am located in let's say "Site B", which is nearly 300 miles away from site A.

I know you can do such tasks on Windows or x86 Linux computers with [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer) (we use it for our other hardware in the same location and it works like a charm), but since the Raspberry Pi is based on an ARM architecture, it isn't supported by TeamViewer yet.

If anyone has ever achieved this, I would be glad to hear how to do it!

Comment: Interesting problem, have you asked on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, posting it there as well!

Comment: Using a relay service like our project Yaler.net enables remote SSH access to a Raspi behind a firewall, NAT or mobile network router.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no ssh access, I can safe you from going on site A once.

I would setup a reverse ssh tunnel for ssh and VNC to a computer on the raspberry:

```
nohup ssh -N -R 3000:localhost:22 you@site-b &
nohup ssh -N -R 3001:localhost:5900 you@site-b &
```

You might implement some "watchog" which reconnects the tunnels if they should get disconnected for some reason. I assume that a VNC server is already running on the raspberry.

On site B you can now use:

```
ssh -p 3000 localhost # ssh to raspberry.
```

or VNC to the raspberry using localhost:3001